# Why did my cluster IDs on my datanodes and namenode go out of sync?

Tags: hadoop

I had the following difficult to debug error in my Hadoop cluster just now.

I have one namenode and 3 datanodes. I'd made some mistakes with my config and so ran the following:

```
namenode$ hdfs namenode -format
namenode$ $HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

But noticed that none of my datanodes were starting. So I looked at the logs and saw:

> 2015-12-08 22:20:07,047 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool  (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to ec2-52-34-138-55.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/172.31.9.93:9000. Exiting.
>   java.io.IOException: All specified directories are failed to load.

After some googling I found someone saying that the cluster ID on my datanodes probably didn't match my namenode. So I checked and this was the problem. I then deleted the data folders in my datanodes and in my namenode, ran the following commands again:

```
namenode$ hdfs namenode -format
namenode$ $HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

and everything is working perfectly.

I would like to know **why** the cluster IDs went out of sync and what is the best way to prevent this from happening again in the future?